# How to display SQL data (4 levelsdeep) in a tree view with C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a SQL table named Notebook.Notes with the following fields (all strings) in it:

| TAB | CONTACT | SUBJECT | NOTES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ERP Project | Doe, Mary | Progress Report | 09/09/2021 9:00 AM - No problems. |
| Engr Project | Doe, Randy | Progress Report | 09/10/2021 10:00 AM - Big problems. |
| Engr Project | Doe, Randy | Problems | 09/10/2021 1:00 PM - Needs 2 engrs added. |
| ERP Project | Doe, Mary | Progress Report | 09/16/2021 9:00 AM - No poroblems. |
| Staff Mtg. | IT Staff | Monthly Meeting | 09/29/2021 11:00 AM - Issues w/Server |

The data is to display like this (3 lines)
Engr Project, ERP Project, Staffing Mtg. When you click on Engr Project, you get Doe, Randy etc.  Instead I get 5 lines displayed ERP Project, Engr Project, Engr Project, ERP Project, Staff Mtg.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is the code.

```
 SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Notebook.Notes ORDER BY Tab;", cn);
        try
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr["Tab"].ToString());
                node.Nodes.Add(dr["Contact"].ToString());
                node.Nodes.Add(dr["Subject"].ToString());
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show(Message ex )
        }
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. Same format as the given data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of each level of nodes, and add them in nested fashion. Something like this:

```cs
treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

const string query = @"
SELECT *
FROM Notebook.Notes
ORDER BY Tab, Contact, Subject;
";
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString))
using (var cm = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
{
    cn.Open();
    TreeNode tab = null;
    TreeNode contact = null;
    TreeNode subject = null;
    using (var dr = cm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if(tab?.Text != (string)dr["Tab"])
            {
                tab = new TreeNode((string)dr["Tab"]);
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(tab);
            }
            if(contact?.Text != (string)dr["Contact"])
            {
                contact = new TreeNode((string)dr["Contact"]);
                tab.Nodes.Add(contact);
            }
            if(subject?.Text != (string)dr["Subject"])
            {
                subject = new TreeNode((string)dr["Subject"]);
                contact.Nodes.Add(subject);
            }
            subject.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode((string)dr["Notes"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- For this code to work properly, you need to have an `ORDER BY` in the SQL. If not, you will need another way to keep track of the nodes, such as a `Dictionary`
- Note the use of a *new* `SqlConnection`, do not cache it
- Note the use of `using` blocks
- You can shorten the code slightly

```
if(tab?.Text != (string)dr["Tab"])
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(tab = new TreeNode((string)dr["Tab"]));
```

- However that syntax can be confusing to some people

Comment: The solution you provided works fine.  I want to change the order of display to Tab, Subject, Contact, Notes.  Here's what I done:1. Change the SQL ORDER BY to  Tab, Subject, Contact,Notes.2. Flip the Contact and Subject if statments modifying the nescessary fields.3. Adding a line after the last if statment to contact.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode((string)dr["DateTime"].ToString() + " " + (string)dr["Note"].ToString()));.  All works fine, except when a Tab has different Subjects with the same Contacts. What is displayed is Tab, Subject, all notes pertaining to both Subjects then Subject only?

Comment: As well as swapping the order of the `if`s, you need to change `contact.Nodes.Add(subject);` to `tab.Nodes.Add(subject);` and `tab.Nodes.Add(contact);` to `subject.Nodes.Add(contact);`